# Is TPM in lockout mode, when uplug a socket of an internal power supply in Lenovo T440s

Tags: bitlocker, tpm

My colleague's Lenovo T440s cannot power on/up yesterday, so I opened up the laptop and unplug the socket of the internal battery. I put everything back to normal and power on, and it powered on, so great I thought I have solved the problem.

when my colleague promte to enter the PIN in BitLocker (the blue screen), the BitLocker said it was incorrect even though the PIN is correct. So I need to go through the recovery key mode, I thought I have saved the right recovery key file, but turns out the identifer in the file is different from the laptop. so technically I do not have the recovery key.

my question is the TPM in the lockout mode? When will the laptop's TPM be unlocked and it will accept the PIN again?

If the TPM is not in the lockout mode, is there any ways to force the BitLocker to accept PIN instead of recovery key

thank you

Answer (score -1):

> My question is the TPM in the lockout mode?

This is likely was caused by removing the battery.

> When will the laptop's TPM be unlocked and it will accept the PIN again?

Unless you provide the correct BitLocker recovery key it will not unlock.

> If the TPM is not in the lockout mode, is there any ways to force the BitLocker to accept PIN instead of recovery key

If BitLocker is now requesting the recovery key, due to the potential of a configuration change, the only way to solve your problem is to provide the recovery key.  **There isn't another way around your issue other than providing the recovery key.**

Comment: To the user who is serial downvoting random answers.  You can stop, all your votes have been reversed, the only thing you will accomplish is to be permanently banned.